# Identity Server 4 API Authentication Failure

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Using .Net Core 2.1 and Identity Server 4

I have 3 startups one for IS4, MVC App, and API App. I am able to log into my MVC application fine, and retrieve my access_token. I try to access the API with this token and am unable to authorize the request.

This is my IS4 Startup.cs localhost:5000

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(configDb =>
            {
                configDb.ConfigureDbContext = db => db.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServer4ConfigurationContext"),
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(IdentityServer4Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(operationDb =>
            {
                operationDb.ConfigureDbContext = db => db.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServer4PersistedGrantContext"),
                     sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(IdentityServer4Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
            })
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

My MVC Startup.cs localhost:61000

```
services.AddMvc();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = "mvc";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.Scope.Add("api1");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                });
```

And my API Startup.cs localhost:62000

```
services.AddMvc();


        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });
```

my Client info is

```
new Client {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "Example Mvc",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "role",
                    "api1"
                },
                RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:61000/signin-oidc"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:61000/signout-callback-oidc" }
            }
```

and API resource

```
new ApiResource {
                Name = "api1",
                DisplayName = "Custom API",
                Description = "Custom API Access",
                UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"},
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("scopeSecret".Sha256())},
                Scopes = new List<Scope> {
                    new Scope("api1"),
                }
            }
```

Whenever I try to call the API while logged in as my Client I cannot access it. It will either give the error

```
[10:40:11 ERR] Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:62000/signin-oidc
{
  "ClientId": "mvc",
  "ClientName": "MVC Client",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://localhost:61000/signin-oidc"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "RequestedScopes": "",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "mvc",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:62000/signin-oidc",
    "response_type": "code id_token",
    "scope": "openid profile api1 offline_access email",
    "response_mode": "form_post",
    "nonce": "636778932114224044.N2M1YzZhMjktMThjMS00ZGEyLWI1OGQtZjM1YmZiMzViNDVkNDQ2NDhjZWMtNzk4Mi00NTc2LWI2YzctNjAwMzkwNjI5NGE5",
    "state": "CfDJ8EzT-5PsjT5Htj2FYGOkFvxTH4w-8q3uXGtc1wXYyvWMHyarfbV0cQz8cFh4ESIW33n4pwtIEmLhrTpX-0Y0-_HS24cWs05nR3npx1ZIAJsYr9hIqB9hj9Ic_QYkU2Z_bcjjnaynqfbF5KIyyQhYGNlDxDfknwZUTXpPzTFEhLTcnam7O-b-xV9a3e9iWARoFZRBLjGV5Hs5i-8jS5EGM9DpqwcvrUjSUlRVDP-TzBBhYPhswn2hKsjkhL26_Gp9lluoKNLOvUVM-yq1zHbbI9uTcZzS_2GtbQoPuuGTmCuOoV-c-K2IztzXP88W-osYaY9wQP2qi8aXD951hrAhYbo",
    "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD1_4",
    "x-client-ver": "5.2.0.0"
  }
}
```

I don't believe I need to have the redirect_uri registered. But I tried it anyway and when I do the same request it will just return the login screen. Because it could not authenticate my request.

Here is the HttpClient request I am sending to the API from the MVC

```
var apiUrl = "http://localhost:62000/test/api";
        var authenticate = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies");
        var accessToken = authenticate.Ticket.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
        return Json(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

From all of the examples and documents I cannot see why this is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the output of IS4 when I try to call the API with the bearer token.

```
[12:38:58 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A62000%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20api1%20offline_access%20email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636779003387253889.MThjYjQ5MzItOTY3NS00NmM1LWJhZDItMzkxMzYyMWQzZTUwZThjNThmMjUtMmQyZC00M2YyLTk3OTktN2E3OTc1ZDcyNmM0&state=CfDJ8EzT-5PsjT5Htj2FYGOkFvzm1YFOhTLHlbLS3LpJd_xUBgDz8hWjGkXxSzfnWKqoVU5d4L7ESHCSDGxqmxqnMh1-j-IUGBLzt5uEYFi2M4QV6WmGN1Lv5bMkUDRbrE9pdCNc7vLDUDZY1OWlp4HfQ0vEMr8-OfUH4Q00fOn1v9zpcE6QlHI5Aye9xiFOshHRyMCNwEEcVrLz4Y06Hsa-40OKom3xb8sie09JtiSMZJL9WyKgKYGRgqUIpD6wqryBafzMl_t1tvegYWESq59TafnIpvrFd3ifdOzJx6cXul4ZCcFv0wfvsqpUgCF7t7xyMSwtheDSiE2AySkbnrpr_Dg&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0
[12:38:58 INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
[12:38:58 INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{
  "ClientId": "mvc",
  "ClientName": "MVC Client",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:62000/signin-oidc",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://localhost:62000/signin-oidc",
    "http://localhost:61000/signin-oidc"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "ResponseType": "code id_token",
  "ResponseMode": "form_post",
  "GrantType": "hybrid",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile api1 offline_access email",
  "State": "CfDJ8EzT-5PsjT5Htj2FYGOkFvzm1YFOhTLHlbLS3LpJd_xUBgDz8hWjGkXxSzfnWKqoVU5d4L7ESHCSDGxqmxqnMh1-j-IUGBLzt5uEYFi2M4QV6WmGN1Lv5bMkUDRbrE9pdCNc7vLDUDZY1OWlp4HfQ0vEMr8-OfUH4Q00fOn1v9zpcE6QlHI5Aye9xiFOshHRyMCNwEEcVrLz4Y06Hsa-40OKom3xb8sie09JtiSMZJL9WyKgKYGRgqUIpD6wqryBafzMl_t1tvegYWESq59TafnIpvrFd3ifdOzJx6cXul4ZCcFv0wfvsqpUgCF7t7xyMSwtheDSiE2AySkbnrpr_Dg",
  "Nonce": "636779003387253889.MThjYjQ5MzItOTY3NS00NmM1LWJhZDItMzkxMzYyMWQzZTUwZThjNThmMjUtMmQyZC00M2YyLTk3OTktN2E3OTc1ZDcyNmM0",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "mvc",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:62000/signin-oidc",
    "response_type": "code id_token",
    "scope": "openid profile api1 offline_access email",
    "response_mode": "form_post",
    "nonce": "636779003387253889.MThjYjQ5MzItOTY3NS00NmM1LWJhZDItMzkxMzYyMWQzZTUwZThjNThmMjUtMmQyZC00M2YyLTk3OTktN2E3OTc1ZDcyNmM0",
    "state": "CfDJ8EzT-5PsjT5Htj2FYGOkFvzm1YFOhTLHlbLS3LpJd_xUBgDz8hWjGkXxSzfnWKqoVU5d4L7ESHCSDGxqmxqnMh1-j-IUGBLzt5uEYFi2M4QV6WmGN1Lv5bMkUDRbrE9pdCNc7vLDUDZY1OWlp4HfQ0vEMr8-OfUH4Q00fOn1v9zpcE6QlHI5Aye9xiFOshHRyMCNwEEcVrLz4Y06Hsa-40OKom3xb8sie09JtiSMZJL9WyKgKYGRgqUIpD6wqryBafzMl_t1tvegYWESq59TafnIpvrFd3ifdOzJx6cXul4ZCcFv0wfvsqpUgCF7t7xyMSwtheDSiE2AySkbnrpr_Dg",
    "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD1_4",
    "x-client-ver": "5.2.0.0"
  }
}
[12:38:58 INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
[12:38:58 INF] Request finished in 138.5606ms 302
[12:38:58 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dmvc%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A62000%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520api1%2520offline_access%2520email%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D636779003387253889.MThjYjQ5MzItOTY3NS00NmM1LWJhZDItMzkxMzYyMWQzZTUwZThjNThmMjUtMmQyZC00M2YyLTk3OTktN2E3OTc1ZDcyNmM0%26state%3DCfDJ8EzT-5PsjT5Htj2FYGOkFvzm1YFOhTLHlbLS3LpJd_xUBgDz8hWjGkXxSzfnWKqoVU5d4L7ESHCSDGxqmxqnMh1-j-IUGBLzt5uEYFi2M4QV6WmGN1Lv5bMkUDRbrE9pdCNc7vLDUDZY1OWlp4HfQ0vEMr8-OfUH4Q00fOn1v9zpcE6QlHI5Aye9xiFOshHRyMCNwEEcVrLz4Y06Hsa-40OKom3xb8sie09JtiSMZJL9WyKgKYGRgqUIpD6wqryBafzMl_t1tvegYWESq59TafnIpvrFd3ifdOzJx6cXul4ZCcFv0wfvsqpUgCF7t7xyMSwtheDSiE2AySkbnrpr_Dg%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NETSTANDARD1_4%26x-client-ver%3D5.2.0.0
[12:38:58 INF] Route matched with {action = "Login", controller = "Account"}. Executing action ASC.ADEX.Runtime.Controllers.AccountController.Login (ASC.ADEX.Runtime)
[12:38:58 INF] Executing action method ASC.ADEX.Runtime.Controllers.AccountController.Login (ASC.ADEX.Runtime) with arguments (["/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A62000%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20api1%20offline_access%20email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636779003387253889.MThjYjQ5MzItOTY3NS00NmM1LWJhZDItMzkxMzYyMWQzZTUwZThjNThmMjUtMmQyZC00M2YyLTk3OTktN2E3OTc1ZDcyNmM0&state=CfDJ8EzT-5PsjT5Htj2FYGOkFvzm1YFOhTLHlbLS3LpJd_xUBgDz8hWjGkXxSzfnWKqoVU5d4L7ESHCSDGxqmxqnMh1-j-IUGBLzt5uEYFi2M4QV6WmGN1Lv5bMkUDRbrE9pdCNc7vLDUDZY1OWlp4HfQ0vEMr8-OfUH4Q00fOn1v9zpcE6QlHI5Aye9xiFOshHRyMCNwEEcVrLz4Y06Hsa-40OKom3xb8sie09JtiSMZJL9WyKgKYGRgqUIpD6wqryBafzMl_t1tvegYWESq59TafnIpvrFd3ifdOzJx6cXul4ZCcFv0wfvsqpUgCF7t7xyMSwtheDSiE2AySkbnrpr_Dg&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0"]) - Validation state: Valid
[12:38:58 INF] Executed action method ASC.ADEX.Runtime.Controllers.AccountController.Login (ASC.ADEX.Runtime), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 41.3848ms.
[12:38:58 INF] Executing ViewResult, running view Login.
[12:38:58 INF] Executed ViewResult - view Login executed in 1.8018ms.
[12:38:58 INF] Executed action ASC.ADEX.Runtime.Controllers.AccountController.Login (ASC.ADEX.Runtime) in 78.939ms
[12:38:58 INF] Request finished in 83.6512ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

I set up my API authentication using `AddJwtBearer` as shown below. And I see you use `AddIdentityServerAuthentication`. May be that's the reason?

```
services.AddJwtBearer(o =>
               {
                   o.Authority = "<id-server>";
                   o.Audience = "<api-audience>";
                   o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
               });
```

And the API controllers have the `AuthenticationSchemes` specified as shown below:

```
[Route("api/rates")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class RatesController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: When I update to that code I get the error `An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Bearer'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, Cookies, oidc. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Bearer",...)?`

Comment: In my case the projects are not just pure API projects. So I do the following -

services.AddAuthentication(...)
             .AddCookie()
             .AddOpenIdConnect(...)
             .AddJwtBearer(...);

I guess you probably removed AddAuthentication? I would suggest adding that back and following the pattern above.

Comment: k25 are you saying to add those to the API startup? Or the MVC

Comment: To the API project, you don't need the AddOpenIdConnect(..) part if its a purely API only project, but you would still need AddAuthentication(...). The stackoverflow link comment will offer some insight perhaps.

Comment: The project has all parts in it, the IS4, API, and MVC. I have a command line that points to a start up job so I can run 3 different applications from the same project. This is to simplify Docket deployment.

Comment: That's perfectly alright. In your question, you have the Startup.cs for the API project. Instead of AddIdentityServerAuthentication, you can use AddJwtBearer and nothing else should change apart from that (and don't forget the API controller attribute part too!)

Comment: I've tried that with no luck. the `[Authorize]` in my controller always returns login page when I call the API. I updated the Question with the logs that IS4 produces when I try to call the API.

Answer (score 1):

You typically only get `Invalid redirect_uri` when the *Client* - i.e. your MVC app - is redirecting to the Identity Server so that a user can authenticate, not when calling the API, nor caused by the API itself, so you should remove the challenge from the API's config and leave that to the UI only.  Your API also needs its secret for some back-channel calls to the Identity Server, so change your API's Startup.cs to this:

```
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.ApiName = "api1";
                    options.ApiSecret = "scopeSecret";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    // You will almost certainly want these at some point too,
                    // to prevent the API talking to the IS for every
                    // API call.  Adjust the duration as desired.
                    options.EnableCaching = true;
                    options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                });
```

You don't show the `Configure()` part of your API's Startup.cs, but ensure it has

```
.UseAuthentication();
```

*before* the call to

```
.AddMvc()
```

Now you should just need to decorate the protected API methods with `[Authorize]` and ensure you pass through the user's bearer token to calls to those API methods.